# Python Pandas - Merging two Dataframes with new and old rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes with rows with an identical (corresponding) index, which I want to merge. Every row has an update-time. For rows with identical indexes the row with the higher update-time wins. All fields from the ‘newer’ row should be taken, except for the fields were only in the ‘older’ row are values.
Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Hugo' : {'age' : 21, 'weight' : 75},
                   'Niklas': {'age' : 46, 'weight' : 65},
                   'Ronald' : {'age' : 76, 'weight' : 85, 'height' : 176}}).T
df1.index.names = ['name']
df1['update_time'] = 1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Hugo' : {'age' : 22, 'weight' : 77},
                   'Bertram': {'age' : 45, 'weight' : 65, 'height' : 190},
                   'Donald' : {'age' : 75, 'weight' : 85},
                   'Ronald' : {'age' : 77, 'weight' : 84}}).T
df2.index.names = ['name']
df2['update_time'] = 2


df1:
+--------+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
| name   |   age |   height |   weight |   update_time |
|--------+-------+----------+----------+---------------|
| Hugo   |    21 |      nan |       75 |             1 |
| Niklas |    46 |      nan |       65 |             1 |
| Ronald |    76 |      176 |       85 |             1 |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
df2:
+---------+-------+----------+---------------+
| name    |   age |   weight |   update_time |
|---------+-------+----------+---------------|
| Bertram |    45 |       65 |             2 |
| Donald  |    75 |       85 |             2 |
| Hugo    |    22 |       77 |             2 |
| Ronald  |    77 |       84 |             2 |
+---------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

Result should look like this:

```
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
| name    |   age |   height |   weight |   update_time |
|---------+-------+----------+----------+---------------|
| Niklas  |    46 |      nan |       65 |             1 |
| Bertram |    45 |      190 |       65 |             2 |
| Donald  |    75 |      nan |       85 |             2 |
| Hugo    |    22 |      nan |       77 |             2 |
| Ronald  |    77 |      176 |       84 |             2 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

How could I do this ? The Problem is to keep the field with the height of Ronald.
If I do first an df.Update of df1 then the timestamp isn't there anymore and i cannot find the older duplicates.
If I do an df.append I can't merge the fields.

Comment: 1st , your input dose not match your output ,2nd you should search before ask .

Comment: When I use combine_first (which I didn't know and I searched al lot before asking) I get exact the upper output with the upper input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

output:

```
          age  height  weight  update_time
name                                      
Bertram  45.0   190.0    65.0          2.0
Donald   75.0     NaN    85.0          2.0
Hugo     22.0     NaN    77.0          2.0
Niklas   46.0     NaN    65.0          1.0
Ronald   77.0   176.0    84.0          2.0
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for for some time. My solution was far more clunky and I'm sure going to make some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting my answer here as parity, being another working solution I have used primarily:

```
rdpz = lambda df: df.groupby(df.index).last()
df3 = rdpz( pd.concat([df1, df2]) )
```

Here, the function `rdpz` groups the concatenated list of dataframes by their indices and chooses the last entry (`first` can be substituted for `last` if list order is reversed).

As said previously, this is not nearly as clean as [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston)'s answer, but helpful if you want to extend to multiple dataframes or have more tricky multiindexes. In one line, you can use:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).apply(lambda df: df.groupby(df.index).last())
```